# Completable Future getting stuck and halts processing indefintely

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, executorservice, completable-future

Hi can someone help as to why the main in below never completes. When I pass 1 to the test method it get stuck completely. However passing 2 makes the run ok. Want to understand the actual issue and also what would be the correct way to code this.

```
public class Test {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, r -> {
        Thread t = defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.test(1).toCompletableFuture().join();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
    public CompletionStage<Void> run(int i) {
        if (i == 1) throw new RuntimeException();
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        future.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());
        return future;
    }
    public CompletionStage<Void> test(int i) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        EXECUTOR.schedule(() -> run(i).handle((output, error) -> {
            if (error instanceof CompletionException) {
                error = error.getCause();
            }
            if (error != null) {
                CompletableFuture<Void> failedFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
                failedFuture.completeExceptionally(error);
                return failedFuture;
            }
            return completedFuture(output);
        }).thenCompose(u -> u).thenApply(future::complete).exceptionally(future::completeExceptionally), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return future;
    }
}
```

EDIT: used solution suggested by holger and working fine. In this solution the handle catches the runtime exception. Why not previously?

```
public class Test {

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, r -> {
        Thread t = defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println("STARTED");
        t.test(1).toCompletableFuture().join();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    public CompletionStage<Void> run(int i) {
        if (i == 1)
            throw new RuntimeException();
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        future.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());
        return future;
    }
    
    public CompletionStage<Void> test(int i) {
        return completedFuture(i).thenComposeAsync(this::run, r -> EXECUTOR.schedule(r, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .handle((res, ex) -> {
                    if (ex == null)
                        return completedFuture(res);
                    if (ex instanceof CompletionException) {
                        ex = ex.getCause();
                    }
                    CompletableFuture<Void> failedFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
                    failedFuture.completeExceptionally(ex);
                    return failedFuture;
                }).thenCompose(u -> u);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? If you change you line to `if (i == 1) return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new RuntimeException("I cannot be 1"));` then it will continue

Comment: @silentsudo told you a way to fix it. Here's why it's broken: Your `run(int i)` method immediately throws a `new RuntimeException()` (it's always called with `i==1`). There's no handler that will catch that exception in your own code. No way for the `future` to be completed.

Comment: As the previous commenters already said, there is no attempt to complete the future when `run(i)` fails immediately. The other question is why you have such a strange structure, i.e. `.handle((output, error) -> …).thenCompose(u -> u).thenApply(future::complete).exceptionally( future::completeExceptionally)` instead of simply `.handle((output, error) -> { if(error != null) future.completeExceptionally(error instanceof CompletionException? error.getCause(): error); else future.complete(output); });` And why use `schedule` with a zero time, instead of just `execute`?

Comment: Your entire `test(int i)` method could be implemented as `return completedFuture(i).thenComposeAsync(this::run, EXECUTOR);` If you want to schedule the execution of the `run(int i)` with an actual, non-zero delay, you could do this like `return completedFuture(i).thenComposeAsync(this::run, r -> EXECUTOR.schedule(r, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));` Both variants solve your issue and are obviously much simpler.

Comment: @Holger i tried to simulate an issue in my org code to understand where the issue is. Removed the scheduling as its not pertinent to use case.

Comment: @Holger would the first handle catch the exception? If not why would not even the complete exceptionally at end catch it? Could any of you explain a little more if possible? I though the first handle itself would have got the exception.

Comment: @silentsudo ^^ same

Comment: Initially noticed this when one junit failed in the exceptional completion. This code also tries retry on the function call. May be that was causing that issue. Will try to add those code as well

Comment: The first `handle` is never invoked if `run` throws an exception, because in that case, `run` doesn't return a `CompletionStage` to invoke `handle` upon. Using `CompletionStage` doesn't change the fundamental execution model of Java: if a method throws an exception, it cannot also return a value.

Comment: @TimMoore used the suggested code by holger. It is working now. and i saw in this code the handle catches the exception, even though its not inside a completionstage. Why is the handle able to catch it here? Added the reworked code also above.

Comment: In Holger’s code, it _is_ inside a completion stage. The syntax `this::run` essentially passes the run method as a lambda to `thenComposeAsync` and does not invoke it immediately.

Comment: Got the root cause now. If i change run().handle() to completedFuture().thenCompose(this::run).handle() in my code initially, it works fine. My comfusion was since the return of the run was completionstage i thought i could directly use it to call handle. @TimMoore thanks for that. I will now read up and experiment to further understand and register it to myself.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. I will raise pr with the service team according to @Holger code as it much more readable.

Comment: "since the return of the run was completionstage i thought i could directly use it to call handle" that would be true _if_ it returned successfully. Since it throws an exception, no value is returned. This is always the case in Java. One alternative solution would be to change `run` to return a failed future instead of throwing an exception, just like the lambda passed to `handle` in the `test` method does.

Comment: The reason it works when you pass `run` as a method reference to `thenCompose` is that the internal implementation of `thenCompose` invokes its function [inside a `try` block](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/8eb90e2d9c4ab5975f4301dbfdb0a6d9fa036af3/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#L646), catches anything it throws, and returns a failed future instead of propagating the exception.